# Can't get View to be drawn in NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, nsscrollview

I am confused about how to implement a `NSScrollView` in the most basic way, so I will describe exactly what I do and hope that it is just to late for me to find my error:

1. Create Xcode project.
2. Adding a NSScrollView into MainMenu.xib.
3. Creating new class inherited from NSView with the drawing method:

   ```
   (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
   {
   [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
   [[NSColor redColor] set];
   NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
   }
   ```
4. Define the view of the NSScrollView to be that new class.

I **expected** to see a **NSScrollView with a red background**. Instead, **I see the scroll view with no modification.**

Comment: Show us your setup in IB.

Comment: How? As a screenshot?

Comment: Set the size of the view as I'm pretty sure you cannot rely on the scrollview to resize the content view (it's the other-way-round; the view is a certain size and the scrollview will accommodate it with scrollers on either/both axis).  So do `self.frame = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 400, 400);` or something in the view's `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: How do you put the view in the scroll view? In IB, or by code?

Comment: @trojanfoe The drawRect method isn't even invoked, I tested using NSLog.

Comment: @DrummerB View is putted in IB.

Comment: Please check the size of view; it's possible `drawRect` won't be called for a zero-sized view...

Comment: @trojanfoe The size is non-zero. At least IB tells me that.

Comment: Please check at runtime.  Use `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Still non-zero.

Comment: OK, and you are sure the `NSScrollView`s **document view** is your custom view? (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Creating.html)

Comment: First, [a zip project to download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19186705/Test.zip). Second, if I use the app delegates applicationDidFinishLaunching to set the document view programatically it works... Question remains, is it not possible to achieve this using the IB only (should the sample project work or not)?

Comment: Ok, I just found that it works perfectly when auto layout is turned off! Why is that? Is there a way of using auto layout and still use this simple approach to have a scroll view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is auto layout. Turn it off and it will work fine.

Comment: Have you found out why is that so? I got the same problem and that solution works, but I would appreciate still having auto layout on.

Comment: @Yrogirg Nope. I was satisfied finding out how I can fix it.